# i am getting transaction exception while executing the insert query by Native-query , how to resolve it?

Tags: jpa, spring-integration

my code is

```html
<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter
  channel="nativeQlChannel"
  native-query="insert into responsestatus(partner_id,response) values (:pid,:response)"
  entity-manager="entityManager" >
  <int-jpa:parameter name="pid" expression="payload['pid']" />
  <int-jpa:parameter name="response" expression="payload['response']" >
 </int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

exception

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your thread is not already running in a transaction, you need to start one, using `<int-jpa:transactional />`.

See [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jpa.html#jpaOutboundChannelAdapterParameters).